# Is it possible to use a wildcard and a punctuation mark on Google search?

Tags: google-search

I'd like to find results from Google Search containing the following pattern: a phrase initiated with the word *because* - followed by any word - and ended with a period. For example: "**because** tired." "**because** happy." "**because** awesome.", etc.

Initially I tried inserting the string `because * .` but two problems arised:

1- The `*` returns results with one or more words and I'd like it to find only a single word before the period (as it works with Microsoft Word).

2- The `.` doesn't seem to be recognized by the search engine. So, is there a way to include punctuation in the search?

Answer (score 2):

### Google

This isn't possible in Google Search, nor any other Google product that I know of, though [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=because+*_NOUN+.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) can tell you what words show up as the wildcard, but not the context. (In this case, Google Books gives poor but technically correct suggestions, like "because Mr." even with some tweaking.)

### Alternatives

Punctuation searches are possible on [english-corpora.org](https://www.english-corpora.org/corpora.asp) (and its Spanish counterpart [corpusdelespanol.org](https://www.corpusdelespanol.org/)), both of which are free to use with an account. In fact, they were built for the type of searching that you're doing. Your search `because * .` will work as-is, or you can use a more specific search like `because NOUN .`, or a broader search like `because * .|!` (using `|` as a symbol for OR). The results will be grouped by word/phrase, and clicking on a single one will show you the context for every hit in that group.

There are some notable differences from a proper search engine like Google, however. While many of the corpora have billions of words, that is still noticeably smaller than what Google indexes. Other than the News on the Web (NOW) corpus, the results are  (and in fact may include dead links). You also can't do a search for results containing multiple words in any order.